# Django is unable to find the view used for query params the other views are working perfectly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

#urls.py

```
from django.urls import include,path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'banks',views.BanksViewSet)
router.register(r'branches',views.BranchesViewSet)
router.register(r'branches/autocomplete/',views.BranchAutocompleteViewSet, basename='branches')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import BanksSerializer,BranchesSerializer
from .models import Banks,Branches

class BanksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Banks.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class= BanksSerializer

class BranchesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Branches.objects.all().order_by('ifsc')
    serializer_class=BranchesSerializer

class BranchAutocompleteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class=BranchesSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        branchName=self.request.query_params.get("q")
        limit=self.request.query_params.get("limit")    
        offset=self.request.query_params.get("offset")
        queryset=Branches.objects.filter(branch__startswith=branchName).order_by('ifsc')[offset:limit]
        return queryset
```

the BanksViewSet and BranchesViewSet are working fine but the other one is not working
the problem might be the basename in urls.py as changing it doesn't do anything even when left as an empty string.

this is what the console has:
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'bankApi.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /branches/autocomplete/
[19/Jan/2021 18:30:04] "GET /branches/autocomplete/?q=A&limit=5&offset=0 HTTP/1.1" 404 12148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your root url `branches` registered **last** like this:

```
...
router.register(r'banks',views.BanksViewSet)
router.register(r'branches/autocomplete/',views.BranchAutocompleteViewSet, basename='branches')
router.register(r'branches',views.BranchesViewSet) # root of 'branches' is last
...
```

Comment: Thank now it's working although there was a small error in views.py All I had to do was typecast limit and offset to int